# Why Does Oracle kill a session at the specific time?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, windows-server

Oracle kills sessions remotely open at the specific time. It means if I open a session at local machine, it is ok. In my case, at every 58 minute.

For example, at 13:58, 14:58, 15:58 and so on.

It means even if I open a session at 13:57, it will be closed *1 minute* after.

My environment is:

- I tested with sqlplus and my python application.
- DB is placed in Windows Server 2012.
- Firewall is turned off.
- Network is connected over local router.

I also checked the Oracle *alert.log*, but there is nothing special.

Any suggestions?

--------------------Edit--------------------

I get a trace logs after setting TRACE_LEVEL_SERVER on sqlnet.ora.

There seems an error but I don't know what it means.

I run two program, one is my app and the other is seqlplus.

They missed connection at the same time 17:36.

Below are the trace log from each.

```
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] ntt2err: soc 4160 error - operation=5, ntresnt[0]=530, ntresnt[1]=53, ntresnt[2]=0
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nserror: nsres: id=0, op=68, ns=12570, ns2=12560; nt[0]=530, nt[1]=53, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=0, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nioqrc: recv: packet reader error -> translated to IFCR_EOF
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nstimarmed: no timer allocated
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nsclose: closing transport
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nsclose: global context check-out (from slot 0) 
complete
```

.

```
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] ntt2err: soc 2216 error - operation=5, ntresnt[0]=530, ntresnt[1]=53, ntresnt[2]=0
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nserror: nsres: id=0, op=68, ns=12570, ns2=12560; nt[0]=530, nt[1]=53, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=0, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nioqrc: recv: packet reader error -> translated to IFCR_EOF
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nstimarmed: no timer allocated
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nsclose: closing transport
[07-4월 -2016 17:36:48:829] nsclose: global context check-out (from slot 0) complete
```

Comment: Definitely an external influence at play here....

Comment: When did this start happening? Have you looked at the "at" command?

Comment: Are there any errors in the alert log or listener logs during the time when the sessions are getting disconnected?

Comment: Maybe more of a post for the superuser forum?

Comment: It is incredibly unlikely that Oracle is killing the session.  Something else is causing the session to be dropped.  I would wager that something at the networking level is causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If the sessions can no longer be reached, this sounds a lot like [Oracle Dead Connection Detection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetdcd-2179641.pdf).

From that paper:

> [image: Extract]

Comment: That does not match the description of the error. The OP says that this happens at specific times of day.